# How can i get object while sending as json from Spring MVC without infinity loops

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

So, i'm trying to get my Student Object to my androidClient from server, but i have ifinity loops. If i use @JsonBackReference/@JsonManagedReference or @JsonIgnore i won't get Object like in case of infinity loop, so i have a question how to do this? Here my classes:

**Student.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    private int id_student;


    @Column(name = "studentName", nullable = false)
    private String studentName;

    @Column(name = "formOfAducation")
    private String formOfAducation;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="id_group")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Group group;

    @Column(name = "studentCourse")
    private String studentCourse;

    @Column(name = "studentSpecializatio")
    private String studentSpecializatio;

    @Column(name = "studentBookName")
    private String studentBookName;

    @Column(name = "studentGender")
    private String studentGender;

    public Student(){
    }

   //getter-setters
}
```

**Group.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "party")

public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    private int id_group;

    @Column(name = "groupName", nullable = false)
    private String groupName;


    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Student.class, mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Student> student;


    public Group(){

    }
```

On client i have the same classes, and when i'm trying to pass only id from group i cant deserialize it on client. Hope you'll help me. Or there's no way to do this, so how can i edit Student object from client?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways.

The  first one is to create DTO objects and initialize them from the entities. Thus you manually stop on desired level without loops.

The second way is to [unproxy](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-a-jpa-proxy-work-and-how-to-unproxy-it-with-hibernate/) the entities to break lazy collection loading which leads to the loops.

Comment: I have DTO object with the same field like in student.java and im trying to get my object by RestTemplate.getForObject How can i get the entity and do i have to change something in my DTO class?

Comment: There should be converters EntityToDTO and DTOToEntity. It's up to you how to implement them. Could be manual copying field by field or reflection based.